# Unable to activate Windows Store app - The app didn´t start

Tags: windows, opencv, uwp

I am trying to create a UWP app (for Desktop) in Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10. Everything works fine, I added some UI elements and I can start the app without problems.

I want to incorporate OpenCV (3.4.9) into my app, which I built using CMake and Visual Studio 2017 (following the steps from https://medium.com/@rabbi.cse.sust.bd/how-to-build-opencv-for-universal-windows-platform-uwp-1a642ec09955)

I have checked the library path for each config (I built one for each x64/Debug, x64/Release, x86/Debug, x86/Release).

The problem starts when I start using OpenCV, eg by including "opencv2/opencv.hpp".

I can still build without errors, but when I try to run the app (Run without Debugging in VS), I get the error:

> Unable to activate Windows Store app. The activation request failed with the error: The app didnt start

When running the .exe directly, nothing happens (I had to add some DLLs to the folder first).

I have tried the suggestions from the similar questions here on SO, but without luck.

Rebuilding or changing configuration doesn´t help.

I can start the app when including "opencv2/core.hpp", and do

```
cv::Mat img;
```

But if I write

```
cv::Mat img(200, 200, CV_8UC3);
```

The same error occurs. Writing

```
cv::Point pt(10, 10);
```

on the other hand works fine.

I am running out of ideas for things to try..

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT Thanks for the input. I followed the linked tutorial on how to built OpenCV, which matches the others I found on UWP. I am using OpenCV for some other projects as well, but not for UWP. The problem with the OpenCV.Win.Core and OpenCV.Win.ImgProc seems to be that they won´t pass the Windows Store checks (like stated in the document you linked), so I won´t be able to publish the app.

Comment: You could try to install OpenCV.Win.Core and OpenCV.Win.ImgProc nuget package to use OpenCV, about this, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/process-software-bitmaps-with-opencv).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the problem. Actually similar to what others with the same issue found:

Visual Studio was unable to find the DLL files for OpenCV. I did suspect that, so I added the bin folder to my path, and copied the DLL files into the project root as well as "ProjectRoot/x64/Release/ProjectName".

But apparently, the DLL files need to be in

> "ProjectRoot/x64/Release/ProjectName/AppX"

for a x64 Release build.

If someone has any idea on why it can´t find them through the PATH or in the project root, please let me know. 
I guess the reason is related to the fact that the binaries are dependent on the configuration?

Anyway, I can load an image through OpenCV in my UWP app now, so I´m happy.

Hope this saves someone a headache.

Comment: UWP applications run in an isolated app container. It has no access to your user environment. That's why the binaries cannot be found in your PATH. Likewise, the project root isn't in the DLL search path.